# Beginner's power supply design

Tags: pwm, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, feedback, stability

I'm trying to design a bench power supply that can be easily controlled by a microcontroller and is more efficient than a simple linear design (although crazy-high efficiency is not the primary target). I've come up with the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6b5cq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've purposefully removed all part values and names to only discuss the overall topology. Here is how I envision it to work:

\$V_{set}\$ and \$I_{set}\$ are two analog voltages that set the target voltage and the maximum current supplied to \$R_{load}\$.

`OA2` will try to keep the voltage at its output such that the PWM value is sufficient to keep the voltage at \$R_{load}\$ to \$V_{set}\$.

`OA1` will rise its output voltage whenever the current flowing through the load exceeds \$I_{set}\$, thus activating Q1 and lowering \$V_{set}\$ to a value such that the current is not exceeded.

Are there any glaring issues with this design? Does it only work in theory, but is useless in practice?

I have not yet decided how the PWM signal will be generated or what the range of Iset and Vset will be, but I thought I'd validate the design before worrying about the details.

Comment: Your output will of course pulse along with the PWM.  That's not usually considered a good thing.

Comment: @JRE Doh! Of course! Would adding an output filter help? Of course it would be tuned to the PWM frequency

Comment: You'll want an output filter far below the PWM frequency.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant "tuned according to what PWM frequency I choose", I was thinking something like 1/8 the PWM freq.

Comment: Why do you think you need M2? \$ R_{LOAD} \$ and \$ R_{SENSE} \$ will pull the output low when M1 is off.

Comment: @Transistor I thought it could be useful in protecting M1 in case of an inductive load

Comment: With an inductive load, when M1 turns off  the inductive current would circulate down through \$ R_{LOAD} \$ and up through M2. A regular snubber diode would do that for you. Maybe there's a good reason but I can't see it.

Comment: Yeah now that I look at it you're probably right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the addition of a simple filter, you have a classic CCM (continuous conduction mode) buck converter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2RaXA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So yes, the overall idea is quite viable, and there's tons of literature about this kind of converter all over the Web.

Without the filter, it doesn't work — you never actually create an average output voltage that you can compare to Vset. You may have been assuming that the load does some sort of filtering implicitly (bypass capacitors?), but that depends heavily on the effective output resistance of M1 and M2, and kills your overall efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Could you also comment on the observations from @Transistor? Is M2 necessary in this case, or can it be avoided and substituted by a flyback diode?

As for the filter: yes, it was a pretty obvious mistake on my part :)

Comment: If you substitute a diode for M2, it will still work (at somewhat lower efficiency), but with light light loads it will be necessary to switch to DCM (discontinuous conduction mode) operation, which complicates the design of the control loop.